# ObjectOutputStream: appending question marks at the beginning of the String

Tags: java, json, typescript1.6

Server(Java) sends a Json String to a client(TypeScript). On the client I get the following: [image]

Therefore `JSON.parse()` fails due to question marks being appended.

**I tried:**

1. Setting content type to - "text/html"
2. Setting encode to - "UTF-8"

And nothing seem to remove these.

**My code:**

```
public class objectOutput {

    static int i=0;
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;

    public objectOutput(HttpServletResponse response)  throws IOException {

        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());  

    }

    // Using this method to write a Json String
    public void writeObject(Object object) throws IOException {

        objectOutputStream.writeObject(object);
        objectOutputStream.close();
        objectOutputStream.flush();       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you shouldn't be using `ObjectOutputStream` if you're just trying to send text. That's not what it's for. `ObjectOutputStream` performs binary serialization in a Java-specific format, of arbitrary serializable objects. It should only be used when the code *reading* the data is also Java, using `ObjectInputStream`.

In this case, you should probably just call `response.getWriter()` instead, or create an `OutputStreamWriter` around `response.getOutputStream()` yourself. (Using `getWriter()` is generally preferred here - the whole point of that call is to create a writer for text responses.)

The content type is unrelated to this problem, but [you should probably change that to `application/json`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type).

Answer (score -1):

Can you try using json format as follows:

```
public class objectOutput {

static int i=0;
PrintWriter pw;

public objectOutput(HttpServletResponse response)  throws IOException {

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    pw = response.getWriter();  

}

// Using this method to write a Json String
public void writeObject(Object object) throws IOException {

    pw.print(object);
    pw.flush();      
    pw.close(); 
}

}
```

Comment: This will not produce JSON. You haven't tried this.

Comment: Yes. The supplying object needs to be JSONObject. @EJP.

Comment: So the signature of the method should be `(JSONObject),` not `(Object)?` Otherwise you just get the result of the object's `toString()` method, which is not preponderantly JSON.

Comment: If I am not wrong, @Sasha supplies JSON String into `writeObject(Object object)` method. So no problem with the existing method declaration. @EJP